# Starting an Autosys job that is already running

Tags: autosys

What happens when you start an Autosys job that is already running? Is the start ignored or is another instance of the job created and executed in parallel with the already-running job?

I know for a fact that issuing a FORCE_STARTJOB against a running job results in an error saying that the job is already running and that FORCE_STARTJOB has no effect, but I'm not sure how a STARTJOB is handled when the job is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that an already running job ignores any FORCE_STARTJOB or STARTJOB messages.