# Autosys Can a job run multiple instance at the same time

Tags: autosys, jil

I am trying to understand autosys job. Suppose I have Job A that runs every 15 minutes. Suppose for some reason if Job A takes more than 15 minutes, will another instance of it run or it will wait for the job to finish before running another instance?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if the previous job run is still running, another instance will not run if the next scheduled time comes. The next time the job runs is when the previous run is finished and the next scheduled time comes.

Another user also experienced this according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656893/1461484).

I did not find any AutoSys documentation that officially confirms what happens in this situation, but I guess the best way to find out is to test it on your AutoSys instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this first hand and can confirm that there won't be two instances in the mentioned scenario. The job will wait on the previous run to complete and will immediately kick off the next instance if the time condition is met before the previous completes.

But this will be the case only when the job is in running state, if the job is in any other state it will kick off based on the given `start_time` condition.